# Do Non-Resident Aliens need to file FBAR?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, foreign-exchange, fbar

I am on F-1 Student Visa doing my STEM OPT now. As per my understanding, I am considered Non-Resident Alien for Tax purposes. Do I need to File FBAR if I have more than 10,000$ in my NRE account?

Comment: Well, there are some 6.7 billion non-resident aliens, and I hope most of them are not filing FBARs. I know I don't, and I have more connection to the USA than most. As for F-1 status, I don't know.